# Framework7 tabs template routing

Tags: routes, html-framework-7

my project are using framework7 template tabbed views. i make this order button so when i pressed it it redirect to history tabs. i've tried using `app.views.main.router.navigate('/catalog/');` it did change home views  to catalog views but not to catalog tabs. it change the home to catalog views

my code

```
path: '/order/',
url: './pages/order.html',
on: {
    pageBeforeIn: function (event, page) {
      // do something before page gets into the view
      //insert picker data from & to value
      var pickerFrom = app.picker.create({
        inputEl: '#from-picker',
        cols: [
          {
            textAlign: 'center',
            values: ['Dukuh Pakis','Dukuh Kupang']
           }
         ]
      });
      var pickerTo = app.picker.create({
        inputEl: '#to-picker',
        cols: [
          {
            textAlign: 'center',
            values: ['Dukuh Pakis','Dukuh Kupang']
          }
        ]
      });
    },
    pageInit: function (event, page) {
      // do something when page initialized
      //order button$$('#harga').html('ggag');
      $$('#pesan').on('click',function(){
        var from = $$('#from-picker').val();
        var to = $$('#to-picker').val();
         app.views.main.router.navigate('/catalog/');
      });
    },
   }
```

Comment: Do You tried this: https://framework7.io/docs/tabs.html#switching-between-tabs

Comment: yes and i don't really get it since i have to redirect it from `routes.js`